# Class Not Found on Chargebee Library in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, autoload, chargebee

I installed Chargebee library to my Laravel web (v5.7).
But when I want to use the library, all the class from the library is not found.
Here is my code on the controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Api\V2\Controllers;

use Chargebee\ChargeBee\Environment as ChargeBee_Environment;
use Chargebee\ChargeBee\Models\Plan as ChargeBee_Plan;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

class ChargebeeController extends Controller
{
  public function retrieveItem($plan) {
    ChargeBee_Environment::configure(env('CHARGEBEE_ENVIRONMENT'), env('CHARGEBEE_KEY'));
    return $plan_response = ChargeBee_Plan::retrieve($plan);
  }
}
```

The `Chargebee\ChargeBee\Environment` and `Chargebee\ChargeBee\Models\Plan` is not found.

Comment: Check the general trouble-shooting instructions for composer first: https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md#general

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found my answer. Apparently it's supposed to be `ChargeBee\ChargeBee`. The 'B' should be capital.